# Appending a new drop down selector using jquery .append method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am wanting to add anther drop down selector every time I press the button. Currently I am using JQUERY to add the new drop down field, however, I am unable to get the new drop down selector added. Currently the code is not working. Below is the code:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuh4c/1/)

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  existingdiv1 = document.getElementById( "dropDown" );    
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("z").append('<strong>Hello</strong>', existingdiv1);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <z>
    <select id="servingSizeUnits" class="selectpicker btn-medium btn-block" data-style="btn-info" name="dropDown" id="dropDown">
       <optgroup label="Select Product Type">
           <option name="dropDown" value="val1">val1</option>
           <option name="dropDown" value="val2">val2 </option>
           <option name="dropDown" value="val3">val3</option>
           <option name="dropDown" value="val4">val4</option>
           <option name="dropDown" value="val5">val5</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
      </z>    
      </div>    
 </div>    

    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary" data-activate="#payment" type="submit">Add Selector</button>
```

Any suggestions would be great.

**Update 1:** I have made sure the SO and fiddle code are the same.

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt have any jquery reference

Comment: Do you want to add a new option, a new select control or a new input type="text"?

Comment: You want this? http://jsfiddle.net/Xuh4c/3/

Comment: Annop, yes you are correct. Before I made this post I was able to add an input field but unable to add the drop down menu selector. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you havent included jquery in your fiddle..I have updated your fiddle and im attaching it here.
http://jsfiddle.net/aR9r9/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
  $(".app").append('<input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="newfield" id="newField" placeholder="New Field">'
  );
  });
});
```

Here im appending the selector with a div thats enclosing the select.

Comment: I have updated the code by giving evry input field a unique id.DO check

Comment: Pranav, Thanks for the answer. I was wanting to add drop down menus when the button was pressed. This code would be cool if we could add both the input field and a drop down menu with the press of the button.

Comment: Ok..I have updated the code..Do check.Just append a select tag along with the input tag

Comment: Pranav, The update is awesome and works well. Thank you for the support in getting a correct answer and extending the answer further by adding the addition of an input field with the drop down menu. I am sure this will be a good resource for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
     count ++; 
    var select = $('#servingSizeUnits').clone().attr('id',$('#servingSizeUnits').attr('id')+count).attr('name',$('#servingSizeUnits').attr('name')+count); 
  $("z").append(select);
  });
});
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuh4c/14/)**

Use jquery **[clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)**

**Note:** You cannot append this -

`<input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="newfield" id="newField" placeholder="New Field">`

as the **Id attribute will be duplicated**, which is not advisable.

Comment: Shaunakde, Thank you for the answered response. Would it also be correct to do the following so that I could have a unique name and id attribute for each new one created? $('#servingSizeUnits').clone().attr({'name',$(this).attr('name')+count, 'id',$(this).attr('id')+count)});

Comment: Yes it would be correct. Just to confirm check the Id's of appended elements by Inspect element -console.

Comment: I attempted replacing the code from the comment above and the button was not adding at all. http://jsfiddle.net/Xuh4c/6/

Comment: Shaunakde, I see the adjustments you made and where I was making my mistakes. Thank you for the updated code.

Comment: Yes, I have it working correctly. I am very appreciative of your help. Thank you.